# How to define colors for histogram in "groupby"?

Tags: python, pandas, colors, histogram

I need to define clients colors (2 colors for 'F' and 'M') for next sample:

```
d = {'gender' : Series(['M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M']),'year' : Series([1900, 1910, 1920, 1920, 1920])}
df = DataFrame(d)

grouped = df.groupby('gender').year
grouped.plot(kind='hist',legend=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need groupby (I don't see that it gains you anything in this case), then you can easily set colors:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
df[df['gender']=='M'].hist(ax=ax1, color='red', label='M')
df[df['gender']=='F'].hist(ax=ax1, color='blue', label='F')
ax1.legend(loc='best')
```